# Website to post recordings of music and play thru browser

Tags: recording, homerecording

Few months ago I saw a post on Music Stackexchange where a person uploaded a sample of their music to get assistance. They used a website to upload their recording and were able to share a link of this recording (i.e. no downloading required).

Unfortunately I didn't note down this website.

Can someone assist?

Comment: SoundCloud maybe?

Comment: There's probably a lot of sites which support playing files withn the browser window.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because offsite resource requests are off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some options:

- [instaud.io](https://instaud.io) (no registration, permanent uploads)
- [vocaroo.com](https://vocaroo.com) (no registration, temporary uploads)
- [soundcloud.com](https://soundcloud.com) (needs registration, permanent uploads)

Feel free to help me improve the answer in the comments.

Comment: You shouldn't use vocaroo for stackexchange though, as the sounds are temporary and they regularly purge them I learnt this to my disadvantage with some older answers on this site.   If you want some more permanent hosting without having to create an account, there's https://instaud.io instead which allows direct upload and is permanent (well, as permanent as any filehost)

Comment: Yes, vocaroo ooks familiar. I will also check instaud.io since @Some_Guy says vocaroo is temporary.

Comment: @Some_Guy I added instaud.io in my answer.

Comment: @Olli Nice.  That's a good answer right there

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict access to people who've got the link, why not just put them on your cloud storage of choice (Google Drive, OneDrive, iDrive, etc.)? All of them

- allow you to restrict access to only the people you share the generated link with
- Will play a sound file in the browser
- Don't require any additional registration other than that you already did when you started using Google / Windows / Apple (there's no doubt a linux equivalent)

That's how my band share our demos and thoughts in between face-to-face rehearsals ...